# Angular ng-click events listeners multiplying with ng-click after $compile

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, twig, symfony-forms, symfony-3.4

Hello Stackoverflow community!

I am working on a Symfony 3 project with AngularJS and jQuery. I created a collection directive to interface with the Symfony form builder to add and remove rows for collection field types. The directive has an isolated scope which sets a 2-way binding variable called prototypeControl. On the twig template site, I call `prototype-control="{{ form.vars.id|camel_case }}Prototype"` to get a unique ID of the collection field so this will work with multiple collection fields in a single form. The weird thing is if I set the variable name to prototypeControl in the prototype-control attribute, everything works fine. The add and delete buttons work on collection rows that exist on load and the delete button works on dynamically added rows. I need this to work with the custom variable name so I can work with the isolated scope functions from the page controller.

Long story short, when I use the variable with the form ID to make it unique, I can trigger the functions from the javscript console but whatever fields are dynamically added, the delete button has no affect what so ever. The only way I can get the delete button to work is to inject $compile into the directive and compile the directvie element.

`$compile(element.contents())(scope);`

Tried with and without the .contents() method. Everything looks good with this approach, delete works both for existing elements and dynamically added elements, the add button works, but for whatever reason, the ng-click on the add button seems to multiply listeners each time. So the next time I click the button, it adds two rows, then after, four rows and so on.

I've tried to compile on different levels of the DOM but the delete button never works. Example elements I've tried is the delete button itself, the DOM stored in the local container variable, tried the prototype HTML itself, and the .prototype-row. None of these seems to have any affect from $compile. Only compiling the element variable seems to work.

Here is the directive:

```
($_ => {
    $_.app.directive('formCollection', [
        '$compile',
        ($compile) => ({
            restrict: 'C',
            require: '^form', // Grab the form controller from the parent <form> element,
            scope: {
                prototypeControl: '=',
            },
            link(scope, element, attr, form) {
                // Declare prototypeControl as an object
                scope.prototypeControl = {};

                // Store the prototype markup in the scope (the template generated by Symfony)
                scope.prototype = attr.collectionPrototype;

                // Determine what the the next row id will be on add
                let row = element.find('.prototype-row').last().data('row');

                // Set the nextRow scope variable
                if (typeof row !== 'undefined') {
                    // Next number in the sequence
                    scope.nextRow = row + 1;
                }
                else {
                    // There are no rows on page load. Setting the default to zero
                    scope.nextRow = 0;
                }

                // Add prototype row (add button)
                scope.prototypeControl.add = ($event) => {
                    if (typeof $event !== 'undefined') {
                        // Prevent Default
                        $event.preventDefault();
                    }

                    // Get the element that will contain dynamically added prototype form rows
                    let container = element.find('.prototype-container');

                    // Replace the __name__ placeholder with the row id (typically the next number in the sequence)
                    let prototype = scope.prototype.replace(/__name__/g, scope.nextRow);

                    // Appened the prototype form row to the end of the prototype form rows container
                    angular.element(prototype).appendTo(container);

                    // Re-compiles the entire directive element and children to allow events like ng-click to fire on
                    // dynamically added prototype form rows
                    $compile(element.contents())(scope);

                    // Increase the nextRow scope variable
                    scope.nextRow++;
                };

                // Remove prototype row (remove button)
                scope.prototypeControl.remove = ($event) => {
                    // Prevent Default
                    $event.preventDefault();

                    // Get the button element that was clicked
                    let el = angular.element($event.target);

                    // Get the entire prototype form row (for removal)
                    let prototypeRow = el.parents('.prototype-row');

                    // Remove the row from the dom (If orphan-removal is set to true on the model, the ORM will automatically
                    // delete the entity from the database)
                    prototypeRow.remove();
                };

                // Manual control to add a row (omits the $event var)
                scope.prototypeControl.addRow = () => {
                    scope.prototypeControl.add();
                };

                // Manual control to remove a row by passing in the row id
                scope.prototypeControl.removeRow = (row) => {
                    // Find the prototype form row by the row id
                    let el = angular.element(`.prototype-row[data-row="${row}"]`);

                    // If the element is found, remove it from the DOM
                    if (el.length) {
                        el.remove();
                    }
                };
            }
        })]);
})(Unicorn);
```

Here is the twig template block for the collection from the server side.

```
{%- block collection_widget -%}
    {% if prototype is defined and prototype %}
        {% set prototypeVars = {} %}

        {% set prototypeHtml = '<div class="prototype-row" data-row="__name__">' %}

        {% set prototypeHtml = prototypeHtml ~ form_widget(prototype, prototypeVars) %}

        {% if allow_delete is defined and allow_delete %}
            {% set prototypeHtml = prototypeHtml ~ '<div class="input-action input-action-delete">' %}
            {% set prototypeHtml = prototypeHtml ~ '<a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-destructive btn-small prototype-remove" ng-click="' ~ form.vars.id|camel_case ~ 'Prototype.remove($event)" data-field="' ~ prototype.vars.id|camel_case ~ '">' ~ deleteButtonText|trans({}, translation_domain)| raw  ~ '</a>' %}
            {% set prototypeHtml = prototypeHtml ~ '</div>' %}
        {% endif %}

        {% set prototypeHtml = prototypeHtml ~ '</div>' %}

        <div class="form-collection" prototype-control="{{ form.vars.id|camel_case }}Prototype" data-collection-prototype="{{ prototypeHtml|e('html') }}">
            {% for field in form %}
                <div class="prototype-row" data-row="{{ field.vars.name }}">
                    {{ form_widget(field) }}
                    {{ form_errors(field) }}
                    {% if allow_delete is defined and allow_delete %}
                        <div class="input-action input-action-delete">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-destructive btn-small prototype-remove" ng-click="{{ form.vars.id|camel_case }}Prototype.remove($event)" data-field="{{ field.vars.id|camel_case }}">{{ deleteButtonText|trans({}, translation_domain)| raw }}</a>
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <div class="prototype-container"></div>
            {% if allow_add is defined and allow_add %}
                <div class="input-action input-action-add">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-small" ng-click="{{ form.vars.id|camel_case }}Prototype.add($event)" data-collection="{{ form.vars.id|camel_case }}">{{ form.vars.addButtonText|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</a>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
            {{ form_errors(form) }}
        </div>
    {% else %}
        {{- block('form_widget') -}}
    {% endif %}
{%- endblock collection_widget -%}
```

Here is the actual template for the paricular collection I'm testing with. This is the content of `data-collection-prototype` which gets dynamically added to the DOM with the `add()` method:

```
<div class="prototype-row" data-row="__name__">
    <div id="proposal_recipients___name__Container">
        <div class="form-item form-item-contact">
            <div id="proposal_recipients___name___contactContainer">
                <div class="form-item form-item-first-name"><label class="control-label required"
                                                                   for="proposalRecipientsNameContactFirstName">First
                    Name<span class="field-required">*</span></label>


                    <input type="text" id="proposalRecipientsNameContactFirstName"
                           name="proposal[recipients][__name__][contact][firstName]" required="required"
                           ng-model="proposalDetails.proposal.recipients[__name__]._contact.firstName"
                           ng-init="proposalDetails.proposal.recipients[__name__]._contact.firstName=''" class="input"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-item form-item-last-name"><label class="control-label required"
                                                                  for="proposalRecipientsNameContactLastName">Last
                    Name<span class="field-required">*</span></label>


                    <input type="text" id="proposalRecipientsNameContactLastName"
                           name="proposal[recipients][__name__][contact][lastName]" required="required"
                           ng-model="proposalDetails.proposal.recipients[__name__]._contact.lastName"
                           ng-init="proposalDetails.proposal.recipients[__name__]._contact.lastName=''" class="input"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-item form-item-email"><label class="control-label required"
                                                              for="proposalRecipientsNameContactEmail">Email
                    Address<span class="field-required">*</span></label> <input type="email"
                                                                                id="proposalRecipientsNameContactEmail"
                                                                                name="proposal[recipients][__name__][contact][email]"
                                                                                required="required"
                                                                                ng-model="proposalDetails.proposal.recipients[__name__]._contact.email"
                                                                                ng-init="proposalDetails.proposal.recipients[__name__]._contact.email=''"
                                                                                class="input"/></div>
                <div class="form-item form-item-phone"><label class="control-label"
                                                              for="proposalRecipientsNameContactPhone">Phone</label>


                    <input type="phone" id="proposalRecipientsNameContactPhone"
                           name="proposal[recipients][__name__][contact][phone]"
                           ng-model="proposalDetails.proposal.recipients[__name__]._contact.phone"
                           ng-init="proposalDetails.proposal.recipients[__name__]._contact.phone=''" class="input"/>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-item form-item-company"><label class="control-label required"
                                                        for="proposalRecipientsNameCompany">Company<span
                class="field-required">*</span></label>


            <input type="text" id="proposalRecipientsNameCompany" name="proposal[recipients][__name__][company]"
                   required="required" ng-model="proposalDetails.proposal.recipients[__name__]._company"
                   ng-init="proposalDetails.proposal.recipients[__name__]._company=''" class="input"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-item form-item-title"><label class="control-label required" for="proposalRecipientsNameTitle">Title<span
                class="field-required">*</span></label>


            <input type="text" id="proposalRecipientsNameTitle" name="proposal[recipients][__name__][title]"
                   required="required" ng-model="proposalDetails.proposal.recipients[__name__]._title"
                   ng-init="proposalDetails.proposal.recipients[__name__]._title=''" class="input"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-item form-item-role"><label class="control-label required" for="proposalRecipientsNameRole">Role<span
                class="field-required">*</span></label>


            <select id="proposalRecipientsNameRole" name="proposal[recipients][__name__][role]" required="required"
                    ng-model="proposalDetails.proposal.recipients[__name__]._role"
                    ng-init="proposalDetails.proposal.recipients[__name__]._role=''" class="hide-search"
                    data-show-search="0" chosen="chosen" data-allow-single-deselect="true" data-placeholder="Select"
                    tabindex="-1">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
                <option value="ROLE_PROPOSAL_SIGNER">Signer</option>
                <option value="ROLE_PROPOSAL_READER">Reader</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-action input-action-delete"><a href="#"
                                                     class="btn btn-secondary btn-destructive btn-small prototype-remove"
                                                     ng-click="proposalRecipientsPrototype.remove($event)"
                                                     data-field="proposalRecipientsName">Remove Recipient</a></div>
</div>
```

I'm still going to bang through this to find the answer. If I figure it out, I'll post back here.

Hoping someone out there ran into this once or twice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I got it working finally after a bit of tweaking. I finally figured out using two directives would prevent the add from multiplying as the add button lives only in the parent directive and elements added are only two the child directive. So I decided to create a directive for the `.prototype-container` div for the prototype rows to live in. That way compiling the `.prototype-container` element will register the dynamically added ng-click events without having to change the way the prototype template is stored in the data attribute.

I am curious to see if anyone sees a cleaner way of doing this however.

I will post the fix for anyone who may be interested in using AngularJS to handle the add and remove buttons with a Symfony collection type. I will also post the CollectionTypeExtension for those who want to try it on their project.

Here is the updated form theme block from the working prototype:

```
{%- block collection_widget -%}
    {% if prototype is defined and prototype %}
        {% set prototypeVars = {} %}

        {% set prototypeHtml = '<div class="prototype-row" data-row="__name__">' %}

        {% set prototypeHtml = prototypeHtml ~ form_widget(prototype, prototypeVars) %}

        {% if allow_delete is defined and allow_delete %}
            {% set prototypeHtml = prototypeHtml ~ '<div class="input-action input-action-delete">' %}
            {% set prototypeHtml = prototypeHtml ~ '<a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-destructive btn-small prototype-remove" ng-click="' ~ form.vars.id|camel_case ~ 'Prototype.remove($event)" data-field="' ~ prototype.vars.id|camel_case ~ '">' ~ deleteButtonText|trans({}, translation_domain)| raw  ~ '</a>' %}
            {% set prototypeHtml = prototypeHtml ~ '</div>' %}
        {% endif %}

        {% set prototypeHtml = prototypeHtml ~ '</div>' %}

        <div class="form-collection" prototype-control="{{ form.vars.id|camel_case }}Prototype" data-collection-prototype="{{ prototypeHtml|e('html') }}">
            <div class="prototype-container">
                {% for field in form %}
                    <div class="prototype-row" data-row="{{ field.vars.name }}">
                        {{ form_widget(field) }}
                        {{ form_errors(field) }}
                        {% if allow_delete is defined and allow_delete %}
                            <div class="input-action input-action-delete">
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-destructive btn-small prototype-remove" ng-click="{{ form.vars.id|camel_case }}Prototype.remove($event)" data-field="{{ field.vars.id|camel_case }}">{{ deleteButtonText|trans({}, translation_domain)| raw }}</a>
                            </div>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            {% if allow_add is defined and allow_add %}
                <div class="input-action input-action-add">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-small" ng-click="{{ form.vars.id|camel_case }}Prototype.add($event)" data-collection="{{ form.vars.id|camel_case }}">{{ form.vars.addButtonText|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</a>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
            {{ form_errors(form) }}
        </div>
    {% else %}
        {{- block('form_widget') -}}
    {% endif %}
{%- endblock collection_widget -%}
```

All I changed in the template is I moved the prototype rows that are already stored and loaded on page load to live in the `.prototype-container` div. This just makes the most sense and allows for the delete button on the directive to work with both instances.

Here is the update JS that includes both directives that communicate with eachother:

```
($_ => {
    $_.app.directive('formCollection', [
        () => ({
            restrict: 'C',
            require: '^form', // Grab the form controller from the parent <form> element,
            scope: {
                prototypeControl: '=',
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attr, formController) {
                scope.formController = formController;
            },
            controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                // Register the child directive scope
                this.register = (element) => {
                    $scope.prototypeContainerScope = element.scope();
                };

                // Store the prototype template from the form theme in the controller prototype variable
                this.collectionPrototype = $attrs.collectionPrototype;

                // Determine what the the next row id will be on add
                let row = $element.find('.prototype-row').last().data('row');

                // Set the nextRow $scope variable
                if (typeof row !== 'undefined') {
                    // Next number in the sequence
                    $scope.nextRow = row + 1;
                }
                else {
                    // There are no rows on page load. Setting the default to zero
                    $scope.nextRow = 0;
                }

                // Controller method to get the next row from the child directive
                this.getNextRow = () => {
                    return $scope.nextRow;
                };

                // Set next row from the child directive
                this.setNextRow = (nextRow) => {
                    $scope.nextRow = nextRow;
                };

                // Prototype control methods from the page controller
                $scope.prototypeControl = {
                    add: ($event) => {
                        $event.preventDefault();
                        $scope.prototypeContainerScope.add();
                    },
                    remove: ($event) => {
                        $event.preventDefault();
                        $scope.prototypeContainerScope.remove($event);
                    }
                };
            }
        })
    ]).directive('prototypeContainer', [
        '$compile',
        ($compile) => ({
            restrict: 'C',
            require: '^formCollection', // Grab the form controller from the parent <form> element,
            link: function(scope, element, attr, formCollectionController) {
                formCollectionController.register(element);

                scope.collectionPrototype = formCollectionController.collectionPrototype;
                scope.nextRow = formCollectionController.getNextRow();
                scope.increaseNextRow = () => {
                    let nextRow = scope.nextRow + 1;
                    scope.nextRow = nextRow;

                    // Set next row on the parent directive controller
                    formCollectionController.setNextRow(nextRow);
                };
            },
            controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                $scope.add = () => {
                    // Replace the __name__ placeholder with the row id (typically the next number in the sequence)
                    let prototype = $scope.collectionPrototype.replace(/__name__/g, $scope.nextRow);

                    // Appened the prototype form row to the end of the prototype form rows container
                    angular.element(prototype).appendTo($element);

                    // Re-compiles the entire directive $element and children to allow events like ng-click to fire on
                    // dynamically added prototype form rows
                    $compile($element)($scope);

                    // Increase the nextRow $scope variable
                    $scope.increaseNextRow();
                };

                $scope.remove = ($event) => {
                    // Get the button $element that was clicked
                    let el = angular.element($event.target);

                    // Get the entire prototype form row (for removal)
                    let prototypeRow = el.parents('.prototype-row');

                    // Remove the row from the dom (If orphan-removal is set to true on the model, the ORM will automatically
                    // delete the entity from the database)
                    prototypeRow.remove();
                };
            }
        })
    ]);
})(Unicorn);
```

And additionally if this is helpful to anyone who wants to use this code for their project, the CollectionTypeExtension.php contents:

```
<?php

namespace Unicorn\AppBundle\Form\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class CollectionTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    /**
     * @param FormView $view
     * @param FormInterface $form
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $view->vars['addButtonText'] = $options['add_button_text'];
        $view->vars['deleteButtonText'] = $options['delete_button_text'];
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'add_button_text' => 'Add',
            'delete_button_text' => 'Delete',
            'prototype' => false,
        ])
        ->setAllowedTypes('add_button_text', 'string')
        ->setAllowedTypes('delete_button_text', 'string')
        ->setAllowedTypes('prototype', 'boolean');
    }

    /**
     * Returns the name of the type being extended.
     *
     * @return string The name of the type being extended
     */
    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return CollectionType::class;
    }
}
```

Special thanks to anyone who may have been trying to reproduce this issue to assist in the resolution of this problem which caused me to bang my head on my desk practically all weekend.

Cheers!